# Decompose 3d affine matrix opencv

Tags: opencv, affinetransform

Here is what I have first:
[image]

As you can see in the image above:

1. There are 3 axis which have as origins O, O1, O2
2. It exists an affine transformation between O and O1 which called M1 (4*4) and the same is applied from O to O2 with M2 (4*4)
3. Also, It is clear that we can compute the transformation between O1 and O2 as I'm describing in the image above.

As we all know, an affine tranformation can be written in the following form:

```
A = Shearing(3*3).Scaling(3*3).Rotation(3*3)
```

Let's say the components of M1 and M2 are known for us and I need to compute the rotation and translation between O2 and O1.
In regards of translation, I could find it as I'm saying in the image above. But for the rotation, it's not clear enough how I can get it. Based on matrix calculations, I end up with this:

```
Shearing(O2->O1).Scaling(O2->O1).Rotation(O2->O1) = Inverse(Shearing(2->O2).Scaling(O->O2).Rotation(O->O2)).Shearing(O->O1).Scaling(O->O1).Rotation(O->O1)
```

Then, to get the `rotation(O2->O1)`, I think I have to decompose `Inverse(Shearing(2->O2).Scaling(O->O2).Rotation(O->O2)).Shearing(O->O1).Scaling(O->O1).Rotation(O->O1)`. So I'm looking for a method in `c++` with `OpenCV` that decomposes the affine matrix. Also, is there any other way to get what I want?